# {"Error":"Invalid JSON syntax at offset 2"} - receiving this error while trying to get everflow report

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, offset

I need to get a report from Everflow, a marketing platform.

The idea behind the code is pretty straightforward - I make a POST request:

```
url = "https://api.eflow.team/v1/affiliates/reporting/daily"
headers = {'x-eflow-api-key': '*MY*API*KEY', 'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
payload = '{ "from": "2020-09-01", "to": "2020-09-10", "timezone_id": 67, "currency_id": "USD"}'

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

What I get as a result is:

```
{"Error":"Invalid JSON syntax at offset 2"}
```

As far as I understand, the problem might relate to the payload format, but no success with it so far after two days of trying.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this Python code?

Comment: In this code snippet, `payload` is defined but not `payload2` i.e. `data=payload2`. Are you sure it's the right one?

Comment: @Azeem yes, that's Python3 code.

Sorry, I didn't fix payload2 first - just was trying to reformat that string - but I get this error with the rigght payload as well

Comment: Right. Please add the Python and Python3 tags as well to your questions. Also, add the complete code so that it can be tested in isolation i.e. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hmm, strange... Did you just try without the space after the `{` in the payload. So it would be `'{"from": "2...` or you may use a false quotation mark in your code, although the json in the payload of the quetsion looks correct...

Comment: And did you try to get the code snippet directly from [their api docu](https://docs.everflow.io/docs/affiliate/reporting#POST_affiliates_reporting_daily). There is a `code snippet` tab that generates the code in python for you

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!
I tried their code but it has issues with quotation marks & needs specifying the content type
However @Parvathirajan Natarajan provided the right answer down below

so, there was no need to quotate the payload (so that would be dict), but at the same time it required json.dumps before passing
Brilliant and super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below code?

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://api.eflow.team/v1/affiliates/reporting/daily"
headers = {"x-eflow-api-key": "*MY*API*KEY", "Content-type": "application/json"}
payload = {'from': '2020-09-01', 'to': '2020-09-10', 'timezone_id': 67, 'currency_id': 'USD'}
payload = json.dumps(payload)
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

But, from requests 2.4.2, the "json" parameter is supported. No need to specify "Content-Type" (in most cases).

```
requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json={'test': 'foo'})
```